# load keras model to java program for prediction new input

Tags: java, keras

I have this code that works for python

```
X = numpy.loadtxt("compiledFeatures.csv", delimiter=",")
model = load_model("kerasnaive.h5")
predictions = model.predict(X)

print(predictions);
```

and I am trying to write a code with the same functionality in java,

I have written this code but it do not works, anyone knows what I am doing wrong or is there another simpler way to do it?

the code is going to the catch block, and during debugging the code it seems that all the information gained from the model file is null

```
path = String.format("%s\\kerasnaive.h5", System.getProperty("user.dir"), 
pAgents[i]);
try {
     network = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(path, false); 
    }
catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("cannot build keras layers");
    }

INDArray input = Nd4j.create(1);
input.add(featuresInput);  //an NDarray that i got in the method 

INDArray output = network[i].outputSingle(input);
```

it seems that the model does not built (the network is still null)
the code for **python loads the model and it works**,

in java i get the error: "Could not determine number of outputs for layer: no output_dim or nb_filter field found. For more information, see http://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras."

although the same file is used in both casses

Thanks,
Ori

Comment: "it do not works" ... can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: it seems that the model is not loaded correctly, after the line


network = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(path, false);
network is still null

Comment: after "the line". what is "the line"? how do you know it's not correctly loaded?

Comment: does it go in the catch block?

Comment: yes it goes to the catch block, I looked during debugging in the import keras model and it seems everything is null inside

Comment: so that's your problem.

Comment: sorry ill be more clear. loading the same model in python works, but it doesnt load in java code although i saw a few exmples that used the same structure of the code.

Comment: any update on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently importing the trained keras model using `importKerasModelAndWeights`. I'm not sure how you trained your model, but in Keras there are two types of models available: the `Sequential model`, and the `Model class` that uses the functional API. You can read more [here](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/).

If you used the `Sequential model` when you created the network, you need to use the `importKerasSequentialModel` function. [Keras Sequential models](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-model-sequential).